# Insufficient funds on bscTestnet when running migrate function on Truffle despite having .5 BNB in the contract account

Tags: deployment, truffle, bsc

The test net transaction is not going through. Do I need to adjust the gas or add more BNB?

I didn't think I have to convert BNB but to ETH but the output I get says that the contract address has 0 wei. I ran truffle migrate --reset --network bscTestnet. I configured the truffle-js file and it doesn't show any errors.

```
Compiling your contracts...
    ===========================
    ✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
    ✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
    > Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
    
    
    Starting migrations...
    ======================
    > Network name:    'bscTestnet'
    > Network id:      97
    > Block gas limit: 30000000 (0x1c9c380)
    
    
    1_initial_migration.js
    ======================
    
       Deploying 'Migrations'
       ----------------------
     *** Deployment Failed ***
    
    "Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
       * Account:  0x84DBfE45a6F5b4dCFc65Efc8ef17b04Cf2F5815F
       * Balance:  0 wei
       * Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
       * Try:
          + Using an adequately funded account
          + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.
    
    
    Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.
    
    
    Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
    
    "Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
       * Account:  0x84DBfE45a6F5b4dCFc65Efc8ef17b04Cf2F5815F
       * Balance:  0 wei
       * Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
       * Try:
          + Using an adequately funded account
          + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The testnet URL in the truffle-config.js file should have been:

https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/
To view the current balance on Metamask I added the "tBNB" symbol and it worked fine. The newer https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s3.binance.org:8545/ was not needed.